# Pass a preprocess variable to a template?

Tags: theming, 8

In *subtik.theme*, I have:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function subtik_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_language') {
    $variables['language'] = $variables['element']['#object']->get('field_language')->getString();
    ksm($variables['language']);
  }
}
```

All good. It dumps 'php' to my page, which is correct.

I also have, in *field--node--field-body.html.twig*, I have:

```
...
{{ kint(language) }}
...
```

Not so good. It dumps 'null' to my page. Why not 'php'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance it looks like you have a condition checking for:

`if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_language') {`

but the template you are using is `field--node--field-body.html.twig` instead of `field--node--field-language.html.twig`.

To get it to pass to field body twig, you would need:

```
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_body') {
    $variables['language'] = $variables['element']['#object']->get('field_language')->getString();
  }
```

Comment: My brain is fried. I need to take a holiday :-) Thanks.